# Determine if a node exists in HTMLAgiltyPack

Tags: windows-8.1, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-8.1

I want run a `foreach` loop in a `HtmlNode` which has been parsed from internet via `HtmlWeb`class and `loadFromWebAsync` method. Before running the loop I want to make sure the that the node exists in the `HtmlDocument`. How do I check that without the help `Xpath` query because many of the `Windows RT` and `Windows 8.1` version doesn't work with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ [`.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to check if sequence contains any element, for example :

```cs
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
.....
var isDivExist = doc.DocumentNode
                    .Descendants("div")
                    .Any();
```

Or to check if any node in the sequence satisfies specific condition :

```cs
var isDivWithSpecificClassExist = doc.DocumentNode
                                     .Descendants("div")
                                     .Any(d => .GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "foo");
```